# App is getting crashed when the button is being pressed

Tags: android, button, tic-tac-toe

This is the code for the button, the android runs perfectly but the button which is supposed to refresh the game makes the app crash..

```
public void playAgain(View view) {
    Log.i("INFO","pressed");
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ImageView counter = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        counter.setImageDrawable(null);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {
        gameState[i] = 2;
    }

    activePlayer = 0;
    gameActive = true;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi there! Please post the crash stack. Also, it seems strange to be calling findViewById(R.id.button) in a random method? Usually you do all that in the OnCreate method.

Comment: Post the error,when carsh as well.please!